# PHP string comparison for unicity

Tags: mysql, unique

I'm working on an inventory solution written in PHP, and I'm facing an issue.

For each item created in my MySQL table, I'm registering the related product's ID, and it's very own serial number (SN) - amongst other specific data.

Keeping in mind that different products *might* share an indentical SN, I cannot go for a **UNIQUE** key on the SN's column.

On another hand, SNs are registerd by hand, and according to the user creating the article, a given SN could be written in different ways : *AE00000121*, *AE 00 00 01 21*, *AE121*, *AE 121*, ...

To add to the complexity, as I am working with several brands, SNs do not share a format, a lenght, or a standard form.

How can I simply check, upon INSERT (or before), that a given SN does not already exists in DB for a given product ID, whatever the way it was written.

I imagined a SQL query counting entries **WHERE id=id and SN LIKE %SN%**, but that does not seem strong enough...

Any help would be appreciated to get that query on foot.

Thanks

Comment: Use a multi-column UNIQUE KEY that contains `(productid, serial_number)`

Comment: That would keep the unicity for several "ways" of writing a serial number ? eg. YF N654 435 S0 321 or YFN654435S0321 ?

Comment: I think you need to identify all of the possible variants that you want to support. From your samples it looks like whitespace can be ignored when comparing, and also that when you have letters followed by numbers, any leading zeros in front of the numbers can be ignored, too.

Comment: Ugh, you shouldn't do that in the DB. The application should canonicalize the data.

Comment: If you want to keep those variants in the column, you could create a generated column with the canonical format, and use that in the index.

Comment: You can have a derived "uniqueness" key thats has all spaces removed, etc. if you're diligent about inserting it that way (Application layer or TRIGGER).